# Loading array from file for android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

```
File sample = new File("words.txt");

Scanner readWords = new Scanner(words);

while(scanner.hasNextLine())
{
    //assume that arrayListOfWords is a previously declared arrayList
    arrayListOfWords.add(readWords.nextLine());
}
```

Will the above code correctly load all the words from a .txt file into an arraylist, assuming that each word is on a separate line, with no blank lines?

I'm developing an android app, so in which of my project folders am I supposed to put the actual file?

When can I put just "words.txt" and when do I have to type the full path name, like C:\Users\etc...

Also, once the program compiles and is turned into an .apk file, how will it still load the words from the .txt file if the file is located on my computer? If someone else uses the app, wouldn't the app not be able to find "words.txt"?

I want to load words into an array without having this massive chunk of code with 1000 ".add()" statements.

I'm using the version of eclipse that came with the ADT bundle provided by Android

Comment: you can put it into asset folder of application.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep only a list of words you can store it in an array under res of your application.
*This solution assumes that you need to keep only a list of words.*

create an xml file array.xml as,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="words">
        <item>word1</item>
        <item>word2</item>
        <item>word3</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

**save this file in res/values/array.xml**

Get the words into an arrayList inside your activity class.

```
String[] arrayOfWords= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.words);
List<String> arrayListOfWords= Arrays.asList(arrayOfWords);
```

Hope this meets your need.
But if you need to keeps the words as a txt file.You can put it in assets folder and read it from your activity.

Answer (score 0):

Put your files in Assets folder & then from your code you can retrieve or read your file by using AssetsManager.

Answer (score -1):

You need to put your file in assets folder of projects. There is a demo for this, you can check it out. http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/05/read-file-from-assets.html